# Forms Authentication - Subfolder Web.Config not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I need an area in my website where only certain users can view.

What I did was create a  Video folder. Under that foler I have folders
One called Login and the other called WatchVid. In the Login folder I have a page called Login.aspx. Once the user logins in they will then go to /WatchVid/Watch.aspx
Below is a representation:

```
    Video Folder
      |
      | 
      ----> Login Folder
      |        |
      |        |  
      |        ---> Login.aspx 
      |
      ----> WatchVid Folder
                 |
                 |
                 --->Watch.aspx
```

I have the following web config file in my WatchVid to only allow roles that have VidUser to view the page:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow roles="VidUser" />
        <deny users="?" />
     </authorization>
    </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

What I am finding is that even if I change:

```
      <allow roles="VidUser" /> 

     To: 

      <allow roles="VidUser1" />
```

I can still get to this the Watch.aspx page ***even though*** I do not have a role of VidUser1.

Am I doing something wrong?

Just as a reference below is the code I use once the user logins in with their userid, pwd:

```
    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(txtUserName.Text, "StreamingUser"))
         {
             const string url = "~/Video/WatchVid/Watch.aspx";
             Response.Redirect(url);
         }
```

Stephan, I have the following in my root web.config page but still letting me get to the Watch.aspx page:

```
        <location path="Video/WatchVid">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
             <allow roles="StreamingUser1dfdfdfd" />
             <deny users="?" />
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
       </location>
```

Note how I created a dummy role of StreamingUser1dfdfdfd just to check  it out. I am still able to get to the Watch.aspx page.

**Mike:**

I have the following under my WatchVid folder but getting access error when I do it with * - Any idea? :

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <configuration>
     <system.web>
     <authorization>
        <allow roles="StreamingUser" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
     </system.web>
     </configuration>
```

I get the following message: 
  *Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.*

Keep in mind that this still works:

```
     protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       if (Roles.IsUserInRole(txtUserName.Text, "StreamingUser"))
       {
         const string url = "~/Video/WatchVid/Watch.aspx";
         Response.Redirect(url);
       }
```

But now it will not let me through to the Watch.aspx page as I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to change

```
<deny users="?"/>
```

to

```
<deny users="*"/>
```

`*` means it is denied to everyone. Then your `allow roles` lets in the right roles.

`?` means it is denied to unauthenticated users. Since you are authenticated, you aren't denied.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Where do I put my web.config. Can I put it in the  WatchVid folder like have it now?

Comment: @NatePet that is a fine place to put it. I prefer doing it that way rather than to put it in root config with the location paths.

Comment: Mike, I am getting an error. I put some comments above next to your name above. Any idea why it is blocking me from viewing the page now. I get authentication error. Thanks

Comment: @NatePet In the button click function you show, you are not setting an authentication cookie... so the fix is going to depend on how you authenticate people and do role management... it could be as easy as doing `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true)`.

Comment: @NatePet but the system is appropriately denying you access... so it means you aren't logged in or aren't in the right role.

Comment: Mike, THANK YOU for your response. I think I am SO close.  I thought if it passes Roles.IsUserInRole(txtUserName.Text, "StreamingUser") I would have the appropriate role of StreamingUser in order to see the Watch.aspx page. Note that when the user registers, I do something like the following: Roles.AddUserToRole(oMU.UserName, "StreamingUser") which gives the StreamingUser role.

Comment: @NatePet you are checking if a particular user is in a certain role... the web.config is having it check to see if the *currently logged in user* is in the role... so you probably aren't logging the person in.

Comment: @NatePet why don't you instead run `Roles.IsUserInRole("StreamingUser")` and see what you get. [Reading for Roles.IsUserInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.isuserinrole.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Mike, that sees to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a location tag at the outermost (root) web.config file.

EDIT to show a (adapted) working example from one of our applications:

```
<authorization>
   <allow users="?" />
</authorization>

<location path="Login.aspx">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>

<location path="Videos/WatchVid">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
      <allow roles="VidUser" />
      <deny users="?" />
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I tried but still have not look. Please look above. I put comments above with your name to reference. Thanks for your help

Comment: hmm. I've copied this one from a working application. Do you have a generic authorization tag with `deny users='?'` missing?

Comment: Just so I am on the same page, I took away the web.config that was in my WatchVid and move the code I with the tweaks you mentioned to the root. I still have the <deny users="?" /> there as you can see. Please let me know if I am doing it right. As mentioned, as this point, I only have 1 web.config file that that one is in the root.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show more details on our (working) environment.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, Still not working -  So you just have 1 web.config file in your root. None in your subfolder, huh? I would be interested to know if you changed what the allow roles were to something bogus if it would still work like it is for me. Thanks again.